# Angularjs translate use $http call the json data instead of using staticfilesloader

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code.

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: './scripts/json/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}])
```

Actually I would like to ask if I can use $http call the restful service then get the json data instead of using staticfilesloader.Can someone give me a sample code?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get some **Json** data from a service, you should definitely use **$http.GET** request.

To make that happen, you simple have to write an $http.Get request on the controller binded to a specific view in which you want to display your data.

**myController.js:**

```
  //You have to pass both $http and $scope                         
  myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope","$http", function($scope, $http){
    //In case of success, data fetched will be stored in data
    $http.get('http://localhost/myDataJson.json').success(function(data){

        $scope.myData=data; //Assigning data fetched by the GET to myData
    });
  }]);
```

**myView.html:**

```
<!--In order to show your data, you have to use this kind of syntax {{myData.fieldName}}-->
<div class="myHeader">
    <span class="headerText">{{myData.headerText}}</span>
</div>
```

**myDataJson.json:**

```
{
    "headerText": "Hello World!"
}
```

**myRoutes.js:**

```
//You have to bind your view to its specific controller defined before
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
  .when('/myView', {
    templateUrl: 'views/myView.html',
    controller: 'myController'
  })

'
.
.
```

There are also other ways to make the same request, also in cleaner ways, but the syntax I written over is the simplest one in my opinion.

If you are a beginner or you are just a bit confused, take a look at:

- [AngularJS http Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
- [AngularJS http W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)
- [Shaping Up With AngularJS by CodeSchool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js)
- [Staying Sharp with AngularJS by Codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/staying-sharp-with-angular-js)

Staying Sharp with AngularJS speaks about managing with AngularJS $http requests and more.

I hope I've been helpful.